# Octopus Deploy check packge before promoting to Production

Tags: octopus-deploy, semantic-versioning, cakebuild

In development we version our builds like so:

```
0.0.0-{branch-name}+{short-git-hash}
```

Something like

```
0.0.0-add-new-button+8ad89d
```

For production releases our versions are normal SemVer:

```
1.2.3
```

I am trying to add a check in octo so that we can't promote any build/package that is a feature branch (`0.0.0-add-new-button+8ad89d`) or a `dev` branch (`0.0.0-dev+8ad89d`) build to Production.

I only want packages generated from `master` (`1.2.3`) to be allowed to be promoted to the Production Environment.

Comment: This is supported using [Channels](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/channels). The scenario is documented on [this blog post](https://octopus.com/blog/channels-walkthrough#step-1-prevent-pre-release-packages-from-being-deployed-to-produ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octopus supports this using [Channels](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/channels). The various scenarios you mention are shown in an excellent video on [this blog post](https://octopus.com/blog/channels-walkthrough).